# AWG 30 cable distance for 3.3V from ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, wire

I'm planing to put some magnetic switches on my windows and pulling the wires up to the attic and use an ESP32 to notify via MQTT when they are opened/closed. I went to my local electronics store and bought a 250m roll of wire which I assumed was AWG 24 at least but turned out to be only AWG 30. My question is will I be able use AWG 30 cable from the ESP32 down to the magnet switch in the window which is roughly 5 meters?

Or is this wire to thin?
What size would you recommend?

Comment: Personally, I'd use #24 or #22 twisted pair cable as it would be considerably more rugged than single conductor #30.  The #30 may be adequate electrically, but seems too fragile for my liking.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Since I will need to pull it through drilled holes I might as well get thicker wires. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: your wire will work just fine, there's hardly any current on a window sensor; 20ma max from the GPIO. To whittle 3.3v down to under 2.6v (the pin's low threshold) at 20ma, it would take about 50 ohms, and 5m of that wire is likely only a few ohms worst-case.